# How to set Font of List View Items to Marathi

Tags: android, truetype

I'm using list view in my app, I want to the font of list view item in marathi, but certain error occurs and app get close. Here is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){ 

        /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(), "akshar.ttf"));
        holder.text1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(), "akshar.ttf"));
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
```

Comment: What the error? Post LogTag piece..

Comment: the error is:-"the application(com.myapp)has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

Comment: POST LogTag MORE THAN one line.

Comment: If you not use this font in application i recommend you to set font in Adapter constructor. And when textview request font you just give him a created instance.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have pasted above is the Adapter class code, then just change

```
holder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(), "akshar.ttf"));
    holder.text1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(), "akshar.ttf"));
```

lines to ..

```
holder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "akshar.ttf"));
        holder.text1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "akshar.ttf"));
```

where

> "context" is the Activity class context which you passing in this adapter class.
>   if still your issue is unsolved then paste ur full code i'll definitely help you..Happy coding.

Comment: sir, if u have such application then please tell me, I did typecasting but now I want to give different names to list items, that's create problem again

Comment: Okay... For u i'v just created a sample app that shows the **ListView with marathi font text view **
just [click to download](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E67AF6549DBEC526!353)

Answer (score 0):

Use "fonts/akshar.ttf" instead of "akshar.ttf".

Answer (score 0):

First download the font file by going to [Click here to download.](http://www.marathimati.com/font/Roupya.ttf)

Then in your project assets folder paste Roupya.ttf file.
in your main activity write
 `Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roupya.ttf");`

and then `yourTextView.setTypeface(typeface);` this will work fine... I've checked then posting this answer.